# Persistence of JQuery Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set up an on-click callback for an HTML that causes another node to become visible. Along the way, I was surprised to find out that the following two statements are not equivalent:

```
$("#title").click($("#content").toggle);
$("#title").click(function() {
    $("#content").toggle();
}
```

The first statement ultimately results in a TypeError when the element is finally clicked, with a message of "undefined is not a function," which I surmised to indicate that whatever I was assigned to the onclick callback ended up being undefined and somehow doesn't persist in memory.

The workaround is simple (just use the statement of the second form), but what I really want to understand is *why* passing the toggle function as an object doesn't work when it finally gets called. I can see that the two are semantically different: the first executes the `$("#content")` call when binding the event and the other executes it when the event occurs, but I don't understand why that should matter.

In case it is relevant to the answer, the code in question is located inside of a function (that has presumably returned by the time the user can click anything).

Comment: The difference is not so much to do with when $("#content") is run, but in how that object relates to the function call - specifically, how it becomes `this` inside the successful call, but is forgotten in the unwrapped version.

Comment: @j08691 No, that would just run the toggle function straight away, whereas the intention was to pass in a reference to that function for later use.

Comment: @IMSoP - whoa, yeah of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***The*** jQuery function, as in this -> `$()`, is just a function, think of it as

```
var $ = function(selector, context) {
   // do stuff with selector etc
}
```

That's really simplified, but when you're calling ***the*** jQuery function (as in `$()`) with a valid selector, it gets the DOM node and returns something like this.

```
[
    0        : <div id="title"></div>, 
    context  : document, 
    selector : "#title", 
    jquery   : "1.11.0",
    .....
    etc
]
```

this is the array-like object jQuery returns, and as you can see `0` is the native DOM node, and it's the reason we can do `$('#title')[0]` to get the native DOM node.

There is however something that one really can't see from a simple `console.log`, and that's the methods that are prototyped onto that array-like object, we could however use a `for..in` loop to see them in the console.

```
var title = $('#title');

for (var key in title) 
    console.log(key)
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/k3q25/1/)

This would return a long list of all the prototyped and non-prototyped methods available on this object

```
get
each
map
first
last
eq
extend
find
filter
not
is
has
closest
....
etc
```

Notice that these are all the jQuery methods added to the `$()` function with `$.prototype`, but jQuery uses a shorter name, `$.fn`, but it does the same thing.

So all the jQuery functions we know are added to the main `$()` function as properties, and the `new` keyword is used internally to return a new instance of the `$()` function with those prototyped properties, and that's why we can use dot notation, or for that matter bracket notation and chain on methods to the `$()` function, like this

```
$().find()
// or
$()[find]()
```

When objects are extended with prototyped properties like this, the value of `this` is also set inside the methods, so now that we understand a little bit about how it works, we can recreate a really simple jQuery version

```
var $ = function(selector, context) {
    if (this instanceof $) {

        this.context = context || document;
        this[0]      = this.context.querySelector(selector);

        return this;

    }else{

        return new $(selector, context);

    }
}
```

This is simplified **a lot** from how jQuery works, but in principle it's the same, when `$()` is called, it checks if it's an instance of itself, otherwise it creates a new instance with the `new` keyword and calls itself again as a new instance.
When *it is* a new instance, it gets the element and the other properties it needs, and returns those.

If we were to prototype on a method to that instance, we could chain it like jQuery does, so lets try that

```
$.prototype.css = function(style, value) {
    this[0].style[style] = value;
}
```

and now we can do this

```
$('#title').css('color', 'red');
```

we've almost created jQuery, only 10000 lines of code to go.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bs5a9/1/)

Notice how we have to use `this[0]` to get the element, we don't have to do that in jQuery when we use something like click, we can just use `this`, so how does that work ?

Lets simplify that as well, as it's crucial to understand why the code in the question doesn't work

```
$.prototype.click = function(callback) {
    var element = this[0]; // we still need [0] to get the element

    element.addEventListener('click', callback.bind(element), false);
    return this;
}
```

What we did there was use `bind()` to set the value of `this` inside the callback function so we don't have to use `this[0]`, we can simply use `this`.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bs5a9/3/)

Now that's cool, but now we can no longer use any of the other methods we've created and prototyped to the object, as `this` is no longer the object, it's the DOM node, so this fails

```
 $('#element').click(function() {
     this.css('color', 'red'); // error, <div id="element".. has no css()

     // however this would work, as we now have the DOM node
     this.style.color = 'red';
 });
```

The reason it fails is because we now have the native DOM node, and not the jQuery object.

So *finally* to answer the question asked.
The reason this works  ...

```
$("#title").click(function() {
    $("#content").toggle();
});
```

... is because you're calling the `toggle()` function, and the correct value of `this` is set, in this case it would be the jQuery object containing `#content` as `toggle()` has no callback that uses `bind()`, it simply passes the jQuery object, an object similar to what we can see at the top of this answer

Internally `toggle()` does

```
$.prototype.toggle = function() {
    this.animate();
}
```

see how it uses `this` directly whithout doing anything other than calling another jQuery function, it ***requires*** that `this` is a jQuery object, **not** a native DOM element.

Lets repeat that, `toggle()` requires that `this` inside the function **is a jQuery object**, it can not be anything other than a jQuery object.

-

Now lets move on back to `click` again, when you do

```
$("#title").click(function() {
     console.log(this)
});
```

the console would show the native DOM element, something like `<div id="title"></div>`

Now we can reference a named function instead

```
$("#title").click(myClickHandler);

function myClickHandler() {
     console.log(this)
});
```

and the result would be exactly the same, we would get the native DOM element in the console -> `<div id="title"></div>`, which is not suprising as this is exactly the same as the one above using an anonymous function.

What you're doing is referencing the `toggle()` function like this

```
$("#title").click($("#content").toggle);
```

It's exactly the same as the example above, but now you're referencing `toggle()`, and when called **it will be called with the value of `this` set to the native DOM element in the click function**, it would go like this

```
    $("#title").click($("#content").toggle);

    $.prototype.toggle = function() {
        console.log(this); // would still be <div id="title"></div>

        this.animate(); // fails as <div id="title"></div> has no animate()
    }
```

This is what is happening, `toggle()` is expecting `this` to be a jQuery object, but instead it gets the native DOM node for the element in the click handler.

Read that again, **`this` inside the `toggle()` function would be the native `#title` element**, which isn't even the correct element, as that's how javascript and jQuery works, see the long explanation above for how `this` is set in the prototyped methods etc.

Comment: It's important to note that even if jQuery set `this` to the jQuery node, rather than the DOM node, it would still be **the wrong node**. If you defined `$.fn.toggle` to use `$(this).animate()` rather than `this.animate()`, you wouldn't get an error, but it would be `<div id="title">` that was animated, not `<div id="content">`. Indeed, this would be true of *any* JS callback, and isn't something jQuery could do anything about - it could set `this` to any value it liked, but it wouldn't have any "memory" of `$("#content")` to use even if it wanted to.

Answer (score 7):

In the first example, you're passing the `toggle` function for jQuery to execute as the event handler.

However, when jQuery *executes* the event handler, it sets the value of `this` to be the DOM element the event fired on.

`toggle`, however, expects it to be the jQuery object (which it *would* be if called normally), as it uses [`this.animate()` in its implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/10024c25820f08139f11d924cec552a26dfbba18/src/effects.js#L579).

This is why you see "undefined is not a function", as `this.animate` is "undefined", and you're trying to call it as a function.

---

It's important to appreciate the resolution of `this` inside a function is deferred until the function is executed. This means a single function can see a different `this` value between invocations. The value of `this` can be altered using `bind()`, `new`, `call()`, `apply()` or by referencing the object differently; for more info see [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html), or [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: I think this needs more explanation of how `this` works in JS: even if jQuery didn't rebind `this` on its callbacks, the `toggle` function wouldn't stay "attached" to the object it came from in the way one might expect.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `this` in a JS function, it refers to *whatever object the function is currently being called on*, not where it was defined. For instance, you can define a function and copy it onto another object, like this:

```
foo = {'name': 'foo'}; bar = {'name': 'bar'};
foo.test= function() { console.log(this.name); }
bar.test= foo.test;
foo.test(); // logs 'foo'
bar.test(); // logs 'bar'
```

When you run `foo.test()`, `this` is set to point at `foo`; but when you run the same function as `bar.test()`, `this` is set to `bar` instead. There is nothing in the function that knows it was originally part of `foo`, so you basically have two separate but identical functions, like this:

```
foo.test = function() { console.log(this.name); }
bar.test = function() { console.log(this.name); }
```

When you run `$("#title").click($("#content").toggle);`, a similar thing happens - you get a reference to the `toggle` function, and *copy that function* into jQuery's list of event handlers. When the callback runs, the `$("#content")` part is forgotten, just like the `foo` was above, so when the implementation in jQuery looks at `this` to see what you want to toggle, it will find the wrong thing.

Exactly what it finds instead has an extra little quirk: jQuery sets `this` on click handlers to be the DOM element that was clicked on (there are various ways in JS of explicitly telling a function what it should use as `this`). The exact error comes about because the implementation of `toggle` is expecting a jQuery object, not a native DOM object, but even if a jQuery object was set as `this`, it would be *the wrong node*: you clicked on `$('#title')`, but want to toggle `$('#content')`, and jQuery has no way of knowing that.

For completeness, to explain why `$("#title").click(function() { $("#content").toggle(); }` *does* work: here the function being saved in jQuery is an anonymous function, which doesn't make any use of `this`, so doesn't care what it gets set to when the callback finally fires. When the event runs (when you click) it calls `toggle` with an explicit context (the object returned by the `$('#content')` lookup), which is exactly what it's expecting.